# Occasional "No Log4j 2 configuration file found" message

Tags: java, selenium, log4j2

**Occasionally**, Selenium does not recognize the Log4j2.xml file which is located under resources that is located under src/main/java. This message is encountered in Eclipse console about 1 out of 5 times.

### "[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3

ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2"##

Below is my Log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>

<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>

 <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>        
                                                    
</Properties>

<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="File" filePattern="${basePath}/prints-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="${basePath}/prints.log">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{  yyyy-MMMM-dd:  hh:mm a :ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500"/>

  
</RollingFile>
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{  yyyy-MMMM-dd:  hh:mm a :ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="trace">
<AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also, my POM.xml file contains following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Where is your `Log4j2.xml` file located?  That's actually more important than what's in it (at least in this case).  Is the file being copied into your jar?  Has the file (or a similarly named file) been copied into your remote test machines somewhere in a classpath accessible area?

Comment: It is located under a folder named 'source' which is, in turn, located under **src/main/java** source folder in the maven project. I do not have any remote machines whatsoever . Inside the repository folder (that is within the .m2 folder), there exists log4j folder, that has another folder named log4j (duplicate) and inside it there exists a folder with the title 1.2.12 where the jars inside are of this version (1.2.12) even though dependencies shown above state 2.11.2.

Comment: You should have the log4j configs in the src/main/resources area, not in the src/main/java area.  Don't worry about multiple versions of anything in the .m2/repository, that's rather the point of maven.